# Server with full php support for Android 2.3.4 on BeagleBoard-xM

Tags: php, android, webserver, xampp, beagleboard

I'm looking for some good opensource webservers for android 2.3.4 gingerbread mounted on beagleboard-xM.
I already used PAW server but the php functions are not good enough.
I need to have a server which exactly has the working capability of XAMP server.
Any suggestions please...??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find something same as xamp... 
There is another application for example (I haven't tested it) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb&feature=related_apps

Other option is to use some "Debian installer" to get clean original Debian on your machine.